# How can i add cc to mail function?

Tags: php

this is my code, But i am getting blank mails also. what was the wrong with this? 
    'success',
            'message'=>'Thank you for contact us. As early as possible  we will contact you '
        );

```
    $name = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['name'])); 
    $email = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['email'])); 
    $subject = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['subject'])); 
    $message = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['message'])); 

    $email_from = $email;
    $email_to = 'To: <someone@gmail.com>, <anotherone@gmail.com>' . "\r\n";

    $body = 'Name: ' . $name . "\n\n" . 'Email: ' . $email . "\n\n" . 'Subject: ' . $subject . "\n\n" . 'Message: ' . $message;

    $success = @mail($email_to, $subject, $body, 'From: <'.$email_from.'>');

    echo json_encode($status);
    die;
```

Answer (score 1):

Please read documentation [mail function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) Here they explained detailedly.

Particularly **Example #4 Sending HTML email**

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
$headers .= 'To: Mary <mary@example.com>, Kelly <kelly@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Birthday Reminder <birthday@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: birthdayarchive@example.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Bcc: birthdaycheck@example.com' . "\r\n";

// Mail it
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: thank you vijayan, Now i can add multiple mails, But the thing is when i send a mail i am getting two in my inbox. one is exacttly what i sent, that from the given mail id, And another one from the server its blank all time. how can i stop these blank mails from server?

Comment: Post your code please @Hafeefkt

Comment: i edited the previous code.. please look at top. help me

Comment: From the code It is clear that it send only one time. Try to debug the code using xdebug to know how code executes step by step using some good IDE. I'm using netbeans.

Comment: i dont knw how to do it. am new to php.. can i hav som tips?

Comment: 1) http://wiki.netbeans.org/HowToConfigureXDebug 2) https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/debugging.html please do as in this two link. You will get some idea.